# Used to and past continuous

Tags: past-continuous, used-to

> The first few weeks or months I **___** that I was eating chocolate or
> cakes, and them I woke up in the morning and my body was crying for
> sugar.
> a) was dreaming b) used to dreaming c) used to dream d) had dreamed

It is obviously, that b and d are wrong, but I see no difference between A and C. **What are the difference between Past continuous and used to?** I was told that C is the correct answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use ***any*** of these "more complex than necessary" verb forms. Why not just use Simple Past ***dreamt*** (or ***dreamed*** if that's your preferred orthography / pronunciation)? If the test doesn't include that option (***and*** gives no context to justify why ***Past Perfect***, for example, might be a meaningful choice) then it's just a rubbish test, not worth bothering with.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I dont want it, it is just a test. And in general, I don't understand difference between Past continuous and used to

Comment: ***used to dreaming*** is syntactic garbage, and ***used to dream*** doesn't really make sense in the context as given. But neither of the other two options make much sense either. It really is a rubbish test. Avoid it, and anything else from the same source.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with "used to dream".  That would be the form I'd've used.  "crying for sugar" is a bit pathetic, but that's not what is being asked about.

Comment: @JamesK Than what is wrong with **was dreaming**?

Comment: @JamesK Do I understand correctly: was dreaming doesn't fit, because the speaker was not dreaming all the time without stopping?

Comment: It's a shame that you've presented such a poor quality context to learn about the difference between Past continuous and "used to". But perhaps the previous question [“Used to” vs Past Simple vs Past Continuous](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147067/used-to-vs-past-simple-vs-past-continuous) will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most tense questions.  It is usually possible to change tense in a sentence and change the meaning, but leave the sentence grammatically correct.

A past tense of some kind is needed here.  The most natural one is "I used to dream".  This can be used to describe a past habit.   ("I would dream" is also possible)

"I was dreaming" suggests continuous dreaming for several weeks or months (grammatically possible, but practically unlikely)

"I had dreamed" suggests an action that occured before the time of the narrative.  But the dreams here occurred at the time of the narrative. So this is less likely

"I used to dreaming" is a grammatical error: The "to-infinitive" is formed with the base form of the verb, not the -ing form.

A simple past tense could also be correct, but the "used to" form suggests that it was generally the case: on many or most nights I had these dreams.